# get checkbox id as array flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I have checkbox flutter so i need to select multiple items from the checkbox and i need to pass to a function as array how do i do that,i can get one data not multiple selected item

```
Container(
            width: double.infinity,
            height: 250,
            child: new ListView.builder(
                itemCount: service_type.length,
                itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index){
                  return new CheckboxListTile(
                      value: inputs[index],
                      title: new Text(service_type[index].service_type_name),
                      controlAffinity: ListTileControlAffinity.leading,
                      onChanged:(bool val){
                        ItemChange(val, index);
                        setState(() {
                          selectedChecboxmenuid=service_type[index].service_type_id;
                          print(selectedChecboxmenuid);
                        });
                      }
                  );

                }
            ),
          )
```

,

Answer (score 1):

All you need to do this create a new field called `isSelected=false` inside the object called `service_type`(not the list, it should inside class)

On on item click, change the status to `isSelected=true` for particular object,

**Ex:**

```
List<int> list = [];

    onChanged:(bool status){
                            ItemChange(val, index);
                            setState(() {
                              service_type[index].isSelected = status;
                              for(var service in service_type) {
                                   if(service.isSelected) {
                                      
                             list.add(service_type[index].service_type_id);
// now pass this list wherever you want
                                  }
                                }
                            });
                          }
```

now we know, which item is selected from the list, so now you can iterate the list and get the `service_type_id` based on `isSelected` flag.

Comment: Sorry about the late reply,I can check the data there is no problem but it just send 1 value at a time,how do i pass let say 2 data from the checkbox to a function so i can pass the value to api like this `[1,2]`@Jitesh Mohite

Comment: for tha first you need to iterate the list called service_type, and find checkbox values which are selected, and add them newly created list, and finally send that to function

Comment: can you please help me with some sample code @Jitesh Mohite